# To redirect to custom html page from another custom made

Tags: javascript, html

Let say I made 3 web pages: fake google, fake facebook, and fake instagram. I am currently at fake google, now I want to go to fake facebook or fake instagram on basis of what I type into the search box. How do I redirect to them using javascript?

```js
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', redirect);

var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value; // this collects value that I have entered in search box for eg fake facebook or fake insta

function redirect(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (newItem == 'fakefacebook')
    window.open('file:///C:/html/index.html');
  else if (newItem == 'fakeinstagram')
    window.open('file:///C:/fakeinsta/index.html');
}
```

I want to open another page after clicking submit. I don't want to open links like google which are already on the internet, I want to open something that I have made on my PC.

Comment: use `window.location.href` instead of `window.open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move getting the value of the text box into the submit handler. At the moment the value for `newItem` is being set when the page loads, and never again.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', redirect);

function redirect(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();

  let newItem = document.getElementById('item').value; // this collects value that I have entered in search box for eg fake facebook or fake insta

  if (newItem == 'fakefacebook')
  {
    window.open('file:///C:/html/index.html');
  }
  else if (newItem == 'fakeinstagram')
  {
    window.open('file:///C:/fakeinsta/index.html');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="addForm">
 <p><label for="item">Input the search term:</label><input type="text" id="item">
 <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```